# News Bar with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make a horizontal "breaking-news" style bar with jQuery. I pick new from the server (the easy part) and I need some way to make them continually scroll from left to right. Any jQuery plugin to help me? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. jScroller
   [Demo](http://jscroller.markusbordihn.de/example/left/)
   [Download](http://jscroller.markusbordihn.de/)
2. Silky smooth marquee:
   [Demo](http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html)
   [Download](http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/)

Answer (score 1):

Good gods, there is a plugin at jQuery site to make BBC style scrolling news ticker check it [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/BBCnewsTicker).

[Here](http://woork.blogspot.com/2008/07/news-ticker-with-horizontal-scroller.html) is an article about making a horizontal scrolling news ticker

An article on [texotela](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/newsticker/) discuss news ticker and ajax.

Answer (score 0):

[Scrollable - Scroll your HTML with eye candy](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable.html)

[Demo here](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/autoscroll.html)

Answer (score 0):

use this Jquery Plugin ..................

http://codecanyon.net/item/breaking-news-ticker/full_screen_preview/8321816?ref=jqueryrain&ref=jqueryrain&clickthrough_id=508633814&redirect_back=true